# In Python, how can I include (not import) one file within another file, macro style, without changing namespace?

Tags: python, macros, include

First I do know about 'import'.  When I try 'import' it doesn't work.  What I'm trying to do is split a single module into two parts, one of which is editable by a group and the other of which is not.  I want the group to write well-defined 'retrieval functions' without the temptation or ability to edit the backend code that runs them (even accidentally).  The changes in namespace on an 'import' are getting in my way.  I'm looking for a macro-style inclusion of File_A's text within File_B, to be run inline as if it were part of File_B.

This is what I'm doing:

I have some generalized code that is designed to call a list of information retrieval functions in turn, and store the info in a unified way.  To do this I add its text name to a list:

```
DataTypes = ['TypeA','TypeB','TypeC']
```

... and then define a function that knows how to get each type, and returns a populated object class:

```
def Get_TypeA:
    # do some stuff to retrieve info
    InfoObj Data
    # Populate Data with the info I got
    return Data

def Get_TypeB:
    # etc. etc.
    return Data
def Get_TypeC:
    # etc. etc.
    return Data

# Backend code below this line, hopefully nobody touches it?
# (But really it would be best if this was in a different file
#  that is harder to mess with and has locked-down permissions.)
class InfoObj:
    # stuff stuff definitions methods etc.
```

These functions will be edited by people with only a basic knowledge of Python but often bad coding habits, but who need to be able to frequently customize what is gathered and displayed.  I already have a backend that checks the list and calls the functions, but I just want to move those definitions into a separate file from the rest of the backend code, but work as if they were right there inline.  (i.e. turn the "hopefully nobody touches it" into a "people have to go out of their way to touch it")

Does Python have this?

When I try using Import, the retrieval functions lose contact with the definition of InfoObj.  This happens whether I use 'import otherFile' or 'from otherFile import *'.

EDIT:  This is what I'm using to retrieve the various types in a standard way:

```
THISMODULE = sys.modules[__name__]

for type in DataTypes:
    RetrievalFn = getattr( THISMODULE, 'Get_'+type )
    Data = RetrievalFn()
    StoreInDB(Data)
```

(though this is boiled down to basics, there are try/except clauses, validation steps to make sure Data was populated correctly and doesn't contain incorrect types or bad stuff, and code to notify the team if and where something breaks but still process the rest of the items.  The goal is that someone making edits does not break the rest of the checks, even if their edits broke one of the checks.)

Comment: You propably *can*, but you shouldn't (and shouldn't have to). Show the exact problems you're having with `import` so we can solve those.

Comment: I have it structured like the above and running, but with the addition of some methods like PopulateDatabase().  That does something like 'for x in DataTypes try to run Get_x, validate it and store it'.  When I cut all the 'def Get_TypeX' functions and paste them into a new file, then import that file, Get_TypeX functions no longer know what an InfoObj is.  I could define InfoObj separately but it's pretty much just for this project.  I feel it's more self-contained this way, though that's probably a bad habit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done with [`execfile()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#execfile), but you should consider using some other mechanism for this instead such as polymorphism or plugins.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly.  I am curious why I might want to avoid this method?  One of my goals is to make it very simple for beginners to define a new info check, without needing training from me.

Comment: It can allow the file passed to poison the namespace of the caller by replacing existing names.

Comment: @Brian, your problem is one of the problems that namespaces are designed to solve. If namespaces are getting in your way, then perhaps you aren't using them to their full potential. But it's hard to tell without understanding more about the architecture of your code.

Comment: The need is to gather information from a variety of sources that need different retrieval methods (usually parsing a web page for specific text).  The information all of the same type, but is accessed differently depending how that vendor set up their software.  The information gets retrieved and then stored in a standard way within a database (instead of umpteen web pages).  The backend defines the database storage and storage classes, executes and validates the retrieval functions, and provides methods for easy access.  The retrieval functions might be edited as often as every few weeks.

Comment: Just want to note, I'll be looking up polymorphism and plugins as possible solutions to refactor this code later.  I don't currently know how to use them is one thing, and possibly needing to know how to use them in order to define a new info check is another. The potential to kill all info checks by badly editing one of them is a worry, something I'm taking steps to avoid, but something we'd notice right away and backrev out of if someone got careless.  (A bad edit to the backend could go unnoticed though and cause a problem months later.)

Comment: Seems I have already created this in a polymorphic fashion. What I have is a number of functions that all return the same type of data object, but have different methods for computing it.  There isn't enough similarity between the functions to warrant inherited classes though.  Calling them by name and keeping a list of names to call seems to be working quite well.  I edited the question to show the method I'm using.